# How to validate array of files?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use this validation rule:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'file' => 'required|file|max:100000',
    ]);
```

Template is:

```
   {!! Form::file('file[]', []) !!}
```

I tried to send `files[]` as array, but my validation rule does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how array validation works. When you're sending `files[]`, you need to check that `files` is an `array`, and `files.*` values are valid `file` with a `max` size:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'files' => 'required|array',
    'files.*' => 'file|max:100000',
]);

{!! Form::file('files[]', []) !!}
```

Note: You input name should match the pluralization of the noun being passed. `file` is singular, and suggests a single `file`, `files` is plural and suggests multiple `files`.

Comment: I get this message `Field "file" must be a file.` What do I do wrong?

Comment: You can't get that error message with the code I've posted. The field is `files`, not `file`